# Python: Merge strings and convert to list of floats

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have several messy lists that contains numbers as strings.  A typical list looks like this:

```
example = ['2', '0', '1', '3', ' ', '=', ' ', '[', '3', '2', '.', '9', '8', ',', ' ', '3', '2', '.', '9', '7', ',', ' ', '3', '2', '.', '5', '9', ']', '\n']
```

I want to convert this into a single "comma" separated list of floats. Using the list example above, the ideal cleaned up list should be:

```
cleanedExample = [32.98, 32.97, 32.59]
```

The length of the floats are not fixed, so sometimes a three decimal might appear.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to extract the bits between the brackets, then join the strings together so you can split by comma, then finally map `float` to get a list of floats.

```
firstBracketIndex = example.index('[') + 1
secondBracketIndex = example.index(']')
numberStrings = ''.join(example[firstBracketIndex:secondBracketIndex]).split(', ')
numbers = list(map(float, numberStrings))
print(numbers)
```

View in action here -> https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/63014174

Answer (score 1):

Given that your array of characters don't contain just the floats, I think it would be better to convert the array into a string and use a regex to extract the floats (e.g. the one defined here) and then parse those floats into numbers.

E.g.

```py
exampleString = "2013 = [32.98, 32.97]\n"

floatRegex = re.compile(r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+")

cleaned = [float(match) for match in floatRegex.findAll(exampleString)]
```

This would currently match the 2013, but you can improve the regex to only capture the values inside the `[]`

Answer (score -1):

this simple approach might help:

```
example = ['3', '2', '.', '9', '8', ',', '', '3', '2', '.', '9', '7', ',', ' ', '3', '2', '.', '5', '9']
float_string = ''
cleanedExample = []
for letter in example:
    if letter == ',':
        cleanedExample.append(float(float_string))
        float_string = ''
    else:    
        float_string += letter 

print(cleanedExample) 
output: [32.98, 32.97]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this below:

```
example = ['2', '0', '1', '3', ' ', '=', ' ', '[', '3', '2', '.', '9', '8', ',', ' ', '3', '2', '.', '9', '7', ',', ' ', '3', '2', '.', '5', '9', ']', '\n']
result = list(map(float, "".join(example).split("= ")[-1][1:-2].split(",")))
# [32.98, 32.97, 32.59]
```

Comment: We don't know how standard that format is though.

Comment: That should be declared by OP.It could work with format `xxx = [....whatever]\n`.Whatever,it could work with the format OP posted.More details should be posted by OP.